# How adding items to list

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have model in my project. Here is code of model

```
public partial class Logging
{
    public string Imei { get; set; }
    public DateTime CurDateTime { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> GPSDateTime2 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Latitude2 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Longitude2 { get; set; }
    public string Speed { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Datatype { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public TimeSpan? FirstStartDifference
    {
        get
        {
            if (CurDateTime != null)
            {
                var midnight = new DateTime(CurDateTime.Year, CurDateTime.Month, CurDateTime.Day, 00, 00, 00);
                var difference = CurDateTime - midnight;
                return difference;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
    [NotMapped]
    public TimeSpan? LastStartDifference
    {
        get
        {
            if (CurDateTime != null)
            {
                var midnight = new DateTime(CurDateTime.Year, CurDateTime.Month, CurDateTime.Day, 23, 59, 00);
                var difference = midnight - CurDateTime;
                return difference;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
    [NotMapped]
    public int coeff = 2;
}
```

I need to get some items from database , it's first entry, where `Datatype==1` and Last where `Datatype ==2`.

So I write this method on back-end

```
public JsonResult GetStops()
{
    using (var ctx = new GoogleMapTutorialEntities())
    {      
        var firstitem = ctx.Loggings.Where(x => x.Datatype == 2).AsEnumerable().Select(
               x => new
               {
                   lng = x.Longitude2,
                   lat = x.Latitude2,
                   difference = (int)(x.FirstStartDifference?.TotalMinutes ?? -1) * x.coeff
               }).FirstOrDefault();
        var lastItem = ctx.Loggings.Where(x => x.Datatype == 2).AsEnumerable().Select(
               x => new
               {
                   lng = x.Longitude2,
                   lat = x.Latitude2,
                   difference = (int)(x.LastStartDifference?.TotalMinutes ?? -1) * x.coeff
               }).LastOrDefault();
        List<Logging> items = new List<Logging> {firstitem, lastItem};
        return Json(firstitem, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

After this I need to add `firstitem` and `lastitem` to list.

I write it like this  `List<Logging> items = new List<Logging> {firstitem, lastItem};`

But I get an error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS1950  The best overloaded Add method 'List.Add(Logging)' for the collection initializer has some invalid arguments   Heatmap C:\Users\nemes\source\repos\Heatmap\Heatmap\Controllers\HomeController.cs   37  Active
>   Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from '' to 'Heatmap.Models.Logging'  Heatmap C:\Users\nemes\source\repos\Heatmap\Heatmap\Controllers\HomeController.cs   37  Active

for this `List<Logging> items = new List<Logging> {firstitem, lastItem};`

How I can add them to List?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning an anonymous type instead of `Logging`. The `firstitem` and `lastItem` are [Anonymous Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types). Change your code to this:

```
x => new Logging
{
    Longitude2 = x.Longitude2,
    Latitude2 = x.Latitude2,
    //And other properties
}
```

And if you still get error probably it is because you cannot project onto a mapped entity then you need to create a [DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) class with needed properties from the `Logging` entity:

```
public class LoggingDTO
{
    public string Longitude2 { get; set; }
    public string Latitude2  { get; set; }
    //And other properties
}
```

Then:

```
x => new LoggingDTO
```

Comment: you mean in query?

Comment: @S.E Yes. In `firstitem` and `lastitem` instead of `x => new` use `x => new Logging` ALSO CHECK MY UPDATED answer about using a DTO class.

Comment: I try to use it, but i have error for this ` lng = x.Longitude2`, Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0117 'Logging' does not contain a definition for 'lng' Heatmap C:\Users\nemes\source\repos\Heatmap\Heatmap\Controllers\HomeController.cs 24 Active

Comment: @S.E You should use the `Logging` properties. `lng` is not a property of that class use `Longitude2 = x.Longitude2` and so on....

Comment: aha. So in front end I can call Longtitude instead of lng for anonymous type?

Comment: @S.E Yes. However I still recommend that use a DTO class. Read my answer carefully.

Comment: Yes. I understood about DTO. Thank's!