# query in Asp.net mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(db.Employees.Select(x => new { x.First_Name, x.Last_Name, 
         x.Email }).ToList());
}
```

There are 5 columns in my table Employee which are `First_Name`, `Last_Name`, `Address`, `Salary`,`Email`. Out of these 5 column I want to display only  `First_Name`, `Last_Name` and `Email` in Browser. 
This is View I am using

```
@model IEnumerable<crudOperation.Employee>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>


        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First_Name)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Last_Name)
    </th>

    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.First_Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Last_Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
    </td>
    </tr>
    }
    </table>
```

I am getting the error as : An unhandled exception was generated during 
the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the  origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

I am beginner to asp.net Mvc. How should I proceed ?

Comment: Can you provide exception details and stack trace to the error? I think `db.Employees.ToList()` is enough, you're returning anonymous type instead of `Employee` table property members.

Comment: Your query returns a collection of anonymous objects, not a collection of `Employee` Just remove your `.Select(...)` and display only those properties of `Employee` you want in the view (but why do you have `DisplayFor()` for properties `Address` and `Salary` if you do not want them?)

Comment: You are sending an anonymous type instead of `Employee` to the view. you need to create a DTO class with needed properties from the `Employee` and then change the view to `@model IEnumerable<YourEmployeeDTO>` like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/46905481/2946329

Comment: Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType4`3[System.String,System.String,System.String]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[crudOperation.Employee]'.

Comment: Stack Trace: 


[InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType4`3[System.String,System.String,System.String]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[crudOperation.Employee]'.]

Comment: @Sho_alam Read the linked answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46905481/2946329

Comment: @StephenMuecke Actually by Removing the select and use Displayfor only for selected column i am able to Display the Required Columns. But i want to Display the Required Cloumns by Using Query.

Comment: Why, and for what purpose?

Comment: @Sho_alam Which query do you want? Just use `Where` to put conditions instead of `Select` all items with anonymous type (`select Employee` instead of `select new`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're sending anonymous object instead of list of `Employee` to the view.

```
db.Employees.Select(x => new { x.First_Name, x.Last_Name, 
         x.Email })
```

Since sending the domain model `Employee` directly to the view is discouraged as you might expose more properties you don't want to display, I would create `view model` for only information you need instead.

### View Model

```
public class EmployeeViewModel
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

### Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var vm = new List<EmployeeViewModel>();

    foreach (var employee in db.Employees)
    {
        vm.Add(new EmployeeViewModel
        {
            EmployeeId = employee.ID,
            FirstName = employee.First_Name,
            LastName = employee.Last_Name,
            Email = employee.Email
        });
    }

    return View(vm);
}
```

### View

```
@model IList<crudOperation.EmployeeViewModel>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First name</th>
            <th>Last name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var employee in Model)
        {
            <tr>
               <td>@employee.FirstName</td>
               <td>@employee.LastName</td>
               <td>@employee.Email</td>
               <td>
                   @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id= employee.EmployeeId }) |
                   @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id= employee.EmployeeId }) |
                   @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id= employee.EmployeeId })
               </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a collection of non Employee object. If you want return List you can use _db.Employees.ToList(), if not you must create a DTO class with properties you want to return.