# Refactoring code with AsEnumerable

Tags: c#, console-application

I have the following code:

```
var results = from table1 in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
join table2 in ds.Tables[1].AsEnumerable()
on table1["VendorNumber"] equals table2["VendorNumber"]
join table3 in ds.Tables[2].AsEnumerable()
on table1["VendorNumber"] equals table3["VendorNumber"]
select new
{ (select clause removed to save space here };
```

I tried to refactor that into a method, but when I did, It gave me errors. The first line of the refactored method was this:

```
private static IEnumerable<> Enumerable(DataSet ds)
```

And the error I'm getting says "Unexpected use of an unbound generic name."

Any suggestions on what I'd need to do in order to be able to correctly refactor this code into a method? Thank you!

Comment: You have to give it a concrete type (which you will return from LINQ). For instance, `IEnumerable<int>`, `IEnumerable<double>` etc. What you have now is open type.

Comment: First of all, you are missing the type for the `IEnumerable`.

Comment: You need to return an `IEnumerable` of a specific type and you have to specify it, but since currently based on your select statement you are returning an anonymous type you can create a DTO class and return it like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/46905481/2946329

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're getting tables from a `DataSet` using **ADO.Net** and trying to join the tables together with **LINQ**. You can't do that. Each `DataRow` in the `DataTable` should be converted into an object equivalent to the data it contains. Then you can join on the objects. For example, If one of the `DataTable` contains `Foo` data:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int FooId { get; }

    public int BarId { get; }

    public Foo(DataRow row)
    {
        FooId = row.Field<int>(nameof(FooId));
        BarId = row.Field<int>(nameof(BarId));
    }
}
```

And the other `DataTable` contains `Bar` data:

```
public class Bar
{
    public int BarId { get; }

    public Bar(DataRow row)
    {
        BarId = row.Field<int>(nameof(BarId));
    }
}
```

Then you'd join them into an `IEnumerable` of anonymous `FooBar` objects like this:

```
var ds = new DataSet();

var foos = ds.Tables[0].Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Select(dr => new Foo(dr));
var bars = ds.Tables[1].Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Select(dr => new Bar(dr));

var foobars = from foo in foos
              join bar in bars
              on foo.BarId equals bar.BarId
              select new { Foo = foo, Bar = bar};
```

You could use `ValueTuple` instead:

```
var foobars = from foo in foos
              join bar in bars
              on foo.BarId equals bar.BarId
              select (Foo: foo, Bar: bar);
```

The `.Field<T>` extension is in `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` by the way!

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify type of collection elements or use type argument

```
private static IEnumerable<T> Enumerable(DataSet ds)
{
    // function body here
}
```

In your case the function returns collection of [DataRow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow(v=vs.110).aspx) elements (see [DataTableExtensions.AsEnumerable Method description](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable(v=vs.110).aspx)). So, you could use

```
private static IEnumerable<DataRow> Enumerable(DataSet ds)
{
    // function body here
}
```